# Attribute in custom class not updating as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to understand creating custom classes, instances and methods in python but things aren't working as I expect.

I created a test class as follows:

```
class otest:

def __init__ (self, name, l_values=[]):
    self.name = name
    self.values = l_values

def add_val (self,value):
    self.updated = self.values.append(value)
```

I load it up with some test data and run the add_val method:

```
a=otest('can',[1,2,3])
a.add_val('a')
```

When I call:

```
a.values
```

I get the expected list of [1,2,3,'a'] but when I run:

```
a.updated
```

It returns an empty list despite setting the new class attribute (updated) equal to the self.values.append(value). Given a.values shows an updated list, the append part is working but it seems I can't set the new attribute to this list? Can someone explain the logic and why?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `list.append()` method appends the element to the list and returns `None`. That's why your code results in `self.updated = None`.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it suddenly all makes sense!